# How to get the EUI-64 part of an IPv6 address in C

Tags: c, ipv6

I wonder if there is a function or any effective way to get the EUI-64 part from my current IPv6 address using C?

Comment: There are no standardized routines to get the EUI-64 part of an IPv6 address; however it's well defined, so writing a routine to do it would not be difficult.

Comment: Thank Petesh for answering my question. In that case, I will do it by myself.